# ≤ not displayed in vf page, renderAs pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

A string containing greater than or less than sign in the Apex class is rendered in vf pdf page without the > or < than operators
example: String in controller = '≤a'
vf pdf page it is displayed as 'a'.

How to display the string as with the sign on vf pdf page.

Comment: I can't reproduce this myself. Copy/pasting ≤ into visualforce directly, using the HTML entity &le;, and copy/pasting it into a String in a controller and using `{!myString}` syntax all work for me. Are you sure that you've used UTF-8 encoding when developing your page/controller? If not, that could be your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update and complete solution for pdf rendering with Special characters**

> If the PDF file fails to display all the page’s text, particularly multibyte characters such as Japanese or accented international characters, **adjust your CSS to use a font that supports them**.

Here `escape` attribute doesn't matter. only following style for font matters where that particular character code supports.

```
<style>
    body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
</style>
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" renderAs="pdf"   applybodyTag="false" 
showHeader="false">
<head>
<style>
    body { font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; }
</style> 
<div>
    {!myvalue}
</div>
<apex:outputText value="{!myvalue}" escape="false" />
</apex:page>
```

**Results:**

[image: pdf render]

Refer [Visualforce PDF Rendering Considerations and Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm)

Comment: Sorry the sign I need to display is '≤'. If the string contains '≤abc' only abc is displayed on vfpage

Comment: ≤ is not a sensitive HTML character (it is quite different from &lt; which is an HTML character), so I'd expect that `escape="false"` would do nothing.

Comment: I have checked that "≤Test" is perfectly displaying for me using that escape="false"

Comment: I don't know why it's not working with you or what is missed in the question,I have tried same and that worked fine for me

My Controller

public class TestOnly{
    public String myvalue {get; set;}
    
    public TestOnly(){
        myvalue = '≤abc';
    }
}

My VF

<apex:page controller="TestOnly" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
      {!myvalue}<br/>
      <apex:outputText value="{!myvalue}" escape="false"/><br/>
      <apex:outputText value="{!myvalue}"/><br/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>


Output is

≤abc
≤abc
≤abc

Comment: It works for me even when explicitly setting `<apex:outputText value="{!myvalue}" escape="true"/>`. This is not the solution to the problem.

Comment: I am trying to print the string on a vf pdf page.